# multi line selection in Sublime text without selecting the blank line

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to select multi line in Sublime without selecting the blank line and replace lamb with goat except the first line. Ctr+Alt selects the blank line as well. Is there a shortcut to do that ?

```
lamb is eating grass

mary had a little lamb

mary had a little lamb
mary had a little lamb
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3: How to do multi-line selection that excludes blank lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222213/sublime-text-3-how-to-do-multi-line-selection-that-excludes-blank-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want to do in your example would be to put the cursor inside the second instance of `lamb` in the file, then press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (or on Mac, <kbd>⌘+D</kbd>) three times to select the last three instances of the text `lamb`, then type `goat`.

Some of the ways to get multiple selections include (for brevity this lists menu items where applicable; see the associated menu entry for the key bound to that function for your platform):

- Adding a cursor to the line above or below the current line via `Selection > Add Next Line` or `Selection > Add Previous Line`
- Select multiple lines and then use `Selection > Split into lines`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> or <kbd>⌘+Click</kbd> to add a cursor at the click location
- <kbd>Shift+Right Mouse Button Drag</kbd> (or <kbd>Option+Mouse Drag</kbd> on Mac) to drag a vertical selection of cursors
- Using `Find > Find` or `Find > Replace` to search for text and pressing the `Find All` button (hover your mouse over the button to see the bound key shortcut for this)
- Using <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or <kbd>⌘+D</kbd> to either select the word under the cursor, or select the next instance of the currently selected text.
- Using the above mentioned <kbd>Alt+F3</kbd> or <kbd>⌘+Ctrl+G</kbd> to quickly select every instance of the word under the cursor or the currently selected text

For your purposes some of these don't apply (since they would select the first instance of Lamb).

Comment: I have edited the contents of the question to make it clearer. In this case, i don't want to update the lamb in the first line.