# Sublime Text 3: How to do multi-line selection that excludes blank lines?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have some scripts in Stata written as follows:

```
* 1. count of firms in each bin
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_0_10 Inear_dist_km_10_30 Inear_dist_km_30_60 Inear_dist_km_60_100 Inear_dist_km_100_150 Inear_dist_km_morethan150, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_gr) emptylabel(empty)
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_gr) name(n1)

* 2. count of firms in each bin (bigger bins)
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_0_20_v2 Inear_dist_km_20_40_v2 Inear_dist_km_40_60_v2 Inear_dist_km_morethan60_v2, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_v2_gr) emptylabel(empty)
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_v2_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_v2_gr) name(n2)

* 3. GGK firm level bins
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_GGK_0_10 Inear_dist_km_GGK_10_50 Inear_dist_km_GGK_morethan50, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr) emptylabel(empty)
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr) name(n3)
```

I need to add the character `;` at the end of each line, but not in the blank lines between each script. I have tried the Split into Lines trick to get multiple cursors at the end of each line, but the selection also includes the empty lines in between. This results in

```
* 1. count of firms in each bin;
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_0_10 Inear_dist_km_10_30 Inear_dist_km_30_60 Inear_dist_km_60_100 Inear_dist_km_100_150 Inear_dist_km_morethan150, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_gr) emptylabel(empty);
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_gr) name(n1);
;
* 2. count of firms in each bin (bigger bins);
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_0_20_v2 Inear_dist_km_20_40_v2 Inear_dist_km_40_60_v2 Inear_dist_km_morethan60_v2, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_v2_gr) emptylabel(empty);
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_v2_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_v2_gr) name(n2);
;
* 3. GGK firm level bins;
grouplabs Inear_dist_km_GGK_0_10 Inear_dist_km_GGK_10_50 Inear_dist_km_GGK_morethan50, groupvar(Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr) emptylabel(empty);
graph hbar (count) if Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr !=1, over(Inear_dist_km_GGK_gr) name(n3);
```

How can I exclude the empty lines from the selection so that only lines with characters in it will have `;` at the end? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're sure that your blank lines are really blank and not filled with whitespace characters use regex substitution by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, search for `(?<!^)$` and replace with `;`.

   - The regex says: find an end of line (`$`) not directly after (`(?<!…)`) the beginning (`^`).
2. Else search for `(?<=\S)$` but make sure you don't havy any trailing spaces or tabs.

   - How to 'make sure': find them with `[^\S\n]+$` and delete.
   - The first regex says: find an end of line directly after (`(?<=…)`) a non-whitespace character, including linebreak.
   - The second regex says: find a sequence (`…+`) of characters that are not any of (`[^…]`) non-whitespace characters or linebreak -- i.e. a sequence of whitespace characters excluding the linebreak -- and then the end of line.
3. The most visual and friendly way might be to

   - find your blank lines with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, search for `^\s*$`,
   - select all with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>,
   - menu > Selection > Invert Selection (now you've highlighted inly the non-blank lines),
   - go on with the original Split into Lines trick.